# How to make the same crosstab line chart by using seaborn or matplotlib?

Tags: python, matplotlib, seaborn, crosstab

I have three columns. But I'm interested in plotting two columns with respect to each other. The datatype of the columns are datetime and object. The datetime column name is  *started_at* and object column name is *member_casual*.
I want *started_at*(hourly) on my x-axis and *member_causal*(count) on y-axis. I use this code

```
    my DaraFrame(df) looks like this
    
rideable_type        started_at             member_casual
electric_bike    2021-06-13 14:31:28            casual
classic_bike     2021-06-04 11:18:02            member
classic_bike     2021-06-04 09:49:35            casual
calssic_bike     2021-06-04 09:55:34            casual
electric_bike    2021-06-04 14:05:51            casual    
classic_bike     2021-06-04 14:09:59            member
electric_bike    2021-06-03 19:32:01            casual
electric_bike    2021-06-10 16:30:10            member
   ...                ...                         ...
   ...                ...                         ...
```

this code gives me line plot of counting member_casual(y-axis) with respect to hourly time(x-axis).

```
pd.crosstab(df.started_at.dt.hour,df.member_casual).plot(kind='line', ax = ax)
```

### Can anyone tell me how to draw the same plot using seaborn or matplotlib ?

I,m begineer so this is the best I can do.

##### try_1

```
 plt.plot(df.started_at.dt.hour, df.member_casual)
```

##### try_2

```
sns.lineplot(df.started_at.dt.hour, hue = df.member_casual)
```

ofcourse both lines of code gives me an error.

Comment: Please provide reproducible test data and yourbest-effort code.

Comment: @JohanC Is this fine now ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You first need to count the hourly occurrences, for instance the same way as you already did:

```
ct = pd.crosstab(df.started_at.dt.hour, df.member_casual)
```

###### matplotlib step by step:

```
plt.plot(ct.index, ct.casual, label='casual')
plt.plot(ct.index, ct.member, label='member')
plt.legend()
```

###### matplotlib short form:

```
plt.plot(ct)
plt.legend(ct.columns)
```

###### seaborn:

```
sns.lineplot(data=ct)
```